# Simple Makefile like bash scripts

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

Shell scripts are essential for any kind of programming, at least you are starting your program of any language by writing a command:

```
$ my-script arguments --options
```

Most of the time you have several tasks. And to remember them you create shell scripts, and commit them, so others can use them too.

There are `Makefiles`, which gives you this feature of named tasks. There is `package.json (scripts)`

...but you cannot run them on any platform, like busybox / alpine, you have to install the dependencies first.

So my question is, is there any alternative to `Makefiles`, maybe a **bash tasks framework** or something without any dependencies, just to write decoupled named scripts, and have them in a single file like Makefiles.

```
# scripts.sh

build:
  docker build -t myproject .

deploy:
  docker push myproject

test:
  smoke_test.sh
```

I am not aware of such, so maybe you guys know some? Thanks!

Comment: There is a POSIX specification for `make`. As long as  you write your Makefile to follow that specification (rather than making use of GNU extensions), you should be able to use it.

Comment: @chepner thx, good to know

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but you can create a `bash` script with a whole load of functions defined in it then dot that (i.e. `source` it) into all your other scripts and call any function, or list of functions, defined in it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell sure, I mean very simple scripts/commands, I've updated my question, thank you

Comment: @chepner Unfortunately neither busybox / alpine docker images support the `make` command, you can install make on alpine, but it takes 228 kB! I think make is great, but it has a lot of features, which I do not need for this purpose

Comment: `case "$1" in build )  docker build -t myproject . ;; deploy ) docker push myproject ;; test ) smoke_test.sh ;; * ) echo "unknown option $1 : ${usage_str:-defined_elsewhere}" 1>&2 ;; esac`. ?? Good luck.